# enchant.jsでのcordovaMediaAPI使用について。

Tags: monaca, cordova

enchant.jsを使用してandroidアプリ作成中です。
cordovaMediaAPIがmonacaデバッカーにて実行中は特に問題なくサウンドの再生が出来ているのですが、デバックビルドして実機（SONY XPERIAZ-3）テストすると「code:0 message:undefined」の後に「code:1 message:undefined」とエラーメッセージが出てサウンドの再生ができません。
※cordovaのプラグインとAndroidManifest.xmlはチェック済みです。

ハイパフォーマンス版でのビルド、cordovaのVer.を3.5.1に変更してもダメでした。
enchant.jsの使用をあきらめた方が良いのでしょうか？

どうかご教示下さい。